# Burninate the [pc] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [pc](/questions/tagged/pc) tag is too broad to be useful and it has been applied to a large range of questions. I suggest it is burninated.

Comment: Only if you burn [macbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macbook), [macbookpro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macbookpro), and [macbook-air](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macbook-air) first. The tags or the actual devices are fine.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Burn all the Apple machines! ***All of them!!***

Comment: A lot of crap to close before burninating though, that's a horrible tag.

Comment: This *is* a really terrible tag. I'm going through some of the questions in it now. I've found a lot with the tag misapplied; the rest are just generally bad questions.